# Simple Android Button Malfunctioning

Tags: java, android, xml, button, onclicklistener

I have a simple Android app that should change the text to "Clicked" When I click a button. However, when I run the code and try to click the button, the button glows blue, but nothing else happens. The main method and the corresponding xml are shown below. Thanks for any help!

```
package com.example.fortesting;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bt);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //tv1.setText("Well, this works");;

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tv1.setText("Clicked!");
        }

    });
    button.setClickable(true);

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

And here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/container">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_bt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="Click Me!" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_bt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare tv1 you must declare it as final to avoid this error when accessing it inside an OnClickListener:

*Cannot refer to a non-final variable tv1 inside an inner class defined in a different method*

Also, move your addListenerOnButton() method call above the SupportFragmentManager block:

```
...
final TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
...
```

Hope this helps!